# CakePHP: can ACL be used to deny editing on specific fields in a model?

Tags: php, cakephp, acl

I have been reading up on CakePHP's ACL component. I understand it can grant or deny certain actions, but can I use it to grant or deny editing for specific fields in a model?
For example, let's say I have a blog application with a Posts model, and an action called Edit. I would like one user to be able to change Post.content, but not be able to change Post.is_published. The is_published HTML input should not be visible for this user.
Can this be done with ACL or do I need to implement this on my own?
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Simply No. ACL is access control list for access controllers and actions it has no any direct relation with Models. What you asked for may be done indirectly across the the controllers methods -actions-!

Comment: Thanks Said! Do you mean I should check in the controllers if the user has this permission and then block or show the correct UI elements? That's what I've been doing so far.

Comment: ACL introduce the handle of access using database tables that handles Acos and Aros. In other word, in large scale project it will make life more easier. However, you may able to introduce your own Acl, for example, in small projects with very limited groups of users yoiu may not need ACL, it is just power field in the users table which is a single character, then every action you want to be manged by access, adding a variable I call it stem which has the powers letters that it accepts access. For example: action view in posts controller $stem="AB" where A is admin power and B is editor power.

Comment: Thanks God I find someone agree with me and think about this idea as awesome!